# Hive: Fetch a row and split the values

Tags: hive

I am running the following hive query to fetch a row

```
select * from hive_table where row_id='x'
```

It returns an output like

10 15 hello world (1 row with four column values).

I am trying to split these values in java so that I could add get the individual column values in an array. Tried splitting them using the ^A delimiter char (the default delimiter when creating a hive table).

```
hive_result.split("\u0001")
```

But it still returns the same result (no splits and returns an array of length 1). Want to know how to split the column vals of a single row fetched from a hive query.

Note: I am running a command-line utility to run this hive query, using jdbc I could use resultSet.next() to get each column separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I need to split the row results by tab instead to control-A. This works fine

```
hive_result.split("\t")
```